# What is the meaning of the count value reported in the moderator's action log?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, flags

In the page that list the actions taken from moderators, I notice something similar to the following text:

> Moderator deletes flag votes - from post id = 21547, count = 0

I understand the log entry is referring to an action taken on a post's flag. What I don't understand is why it is always reported, "count = 0."

I also don't understand the following entry:

> Moderator deletes flag votes - from post id = 21801, count = 0
>   Moderator deletes flag votes - from post id = 21801, count = 0
>   Moderator deletes flag votes - from post id = 21801, count = 1

What is the meaning of the "count" value? Why in the latter entry, the value of that parameter is reported three times? What is the difference between "count = 0," and "count = 1"?

Comment: always wondered that too!